# JSQMessagesViewController - Make tailless bubble for image message

Tags: objective-c, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am trying to create a JSQMessage with MediaItem that is without a tail.

I am creating the message with:

```
JSQMessage* imageMessage = [JSQMessage messageWithSenderId:fileMessage.sender.userId displayName:senderUser[@"nickname"] media:mediaItem];
```

however I don't see an option to customise the bubble. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define your bubble style at the top of your file.

```
        incomingBubble = JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory(bubble: UIImage.jsq_bubbleCompactTailless(), capInsets: UIEdgeInsets.zero, layoutDirection: UIApplication.shared.userInterfaceLayoutDirection).incomingMessagesBubbleImage(with: UIColor.jsq_messageBubbleBlue())
        outgoingBubble = JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory(bubble: UIImage.jsq_bubbleCompactTailless(), capInsets: UIEdgeInsets.zero, layoutDirection: UIApplication.shared.userInterfaceLayoutDirection).outgoingMessagesBubbleImage(with: UIColor.lightGray)
```

Comment: And how will 'JSQMessagesViewController' know to use these variables? They can't be intered in my 'JSQMessage' declaration.

Comment: These are the variables that the library uses for the bubbles already. You are not defining `var incomingBubble` your are just setting it. The library is already using them it is just giving you an access point for styling them the way you would like.

Comment: @DanLeonard is recording and send audio functionality like WhatsApp available in this library because I didn't find it in the library's document. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't believe it is supported by default but it has been built in such a way that you can add your own Message types and have them integrated. So simple answer is no but the library will allow you to add support for it.